How to extract value from attribute with Hyphen in them using BeautifulSoup
I have the below code:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
for img in tqdm(soup.find_all("img"), "Extracting images"):
    img_url = str(img.attrs.get("data-src"))
    print(img_url)
    img_url = str(img.attrs.get("data"))
    print(img_url)

It works when I trying to get the data form src, but when I try to get the data from data-src" it does not work when there is a Hyphen
<img alt="" class="lazy" src="https://www.url.com/assets/images/new-search-icon.svg"/>
<img alt="" class="lazyload" data-src="https://url.tv/bcci/photos/1354/887cffe6-0664-4146-9e7b-27b83d71db56.jpg"/>

Any idea how I can get the details from attribute with a hyphen?

what you have should work, what is the error?

have you checked the content of your request?

there was no error, it was not retrieving the value, the result type was NoneType

I change the below to final the request with the specific attribute "data-src", it worked:
for img in tqdm(soup.find_all("img"), "Extracting images"):
    img_url = str(img.attrs.get("data-src"))

to:
for img in tqdm(soup.find_all("img", {"data-src": True}), "Extracting images"):
    img_url = img.attrs.get("data-src") #Old Urls were downloading from src

This actually worked, previously when I try to get the value using the attribute "data-src", it did not work. I had to include it in the find as well.
